# Manter ordem de itens no JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Tem como manter a ordem dos itens que vieram no `JSON` de uma `API`?

Este é como esta chegando da `API`:

> `{"6":"Abadia","218":"Abel Reis","44":"Alexandre Campos - Jardim","13":"Alfredo Freire I","174":"Alfredo Freire II","186":"Alfredo Freire III","217":"Alfredo Freire IV","189":"Alvorada I, Jardim","190":"Alvorada II, Jardim","55":"Am\u00e9rica - Jardim","80":"Amoroso Costa","254":"Anita, Jardim","137":"Antonia"}`

e quando eu uso ele num `select` por exemplo o `JSON` esta sendo organizado pelo `index` e não pelo `texto`, ou seja, ficando assim:

> 1: "Centro"
>   2: "São Benedito"
>   3: "Santa Maria"
>   6: "Abadia"
>   8: "Grande Horizonte"
>   9: "Boa Vista"
>   10: "Mercês"
>   11: "Rec. dos Bandeirantes"

Comment: Verifique se API pode  odernar se não tem que ser feito a ordenação no Javascript

Comment: O objeto está em ordem alfabética e vc quer manter assim no select é isto?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic amigo a API esta enviando ja organizado certinho. O problema é no Javascript que esta organizando pelo índice. Sendo que o certo é organizar pelo texto e não pelo índice.

Comment: @Leandro isto mesmo. Eu quero manter a ordem alfabética dos valores e não a numérica do índice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Quando os nomes das chaves são apenas numéricos, o JavaScript
>   automaticamente reordena em ordem numérica.

Mas você pode reordenar as options do `select` usando `sort()`. Após popular o `select`, use o código abaixo, que irá reestruturar as options ordenando-as em ordem alfabética pelo texto:

```
// seleciona o select. Altere para o id ou classe usada no select
var sel = document.body.querySelector("select");

// seleciona as options como array
var sel_opts = Array.apply(null, sel.childNodes);

// aplico o sort
sel_opts.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.text.localeCompare(b.text);
});

// vou criar a coleção das options em HTML
opts = "";
for(var chave of sel_opts) {
   opts += chave.outerHTML;
}

// substituo as options ordenadas no select
sel.innerHTML = opts;
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
var obj = {
   "6":"Abadia",
   "218":"Abel Reis",
   "1":"Centro",
   "2":"São Benedito",
   "174":"Alfredo Freire II",
   "3":"Santa Maria"
   }

var opts = "";
for(var chave in obj) {
   opts += '<option value="'+chave+'">'+obj[chave]+'</option>';
}

var sel = document.body.querySelector("select");
sel.innerHTML = opts;

var sel_opts = Array.apply(null, sel.childNodes);

sel_opts.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.text.localeCompare(b.text);
});

opts = "";
for(var chave of sel_opts) {
   opts += chave.outerHTML;
}

sel.innerHTML = opts;
```

```html
<select>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

Ao contrario dos Arrays, um Objeto não tem a obrigação de manter a ordem das chaves.

Se você quer manter a ordem dos itens, deve enviar um array.

```js
var json = [
  { key: "6", value: "Abadia" },
  { key: "218", value: "Abel Reis" },
  { key: "44", value: "Alexandre Campos - Jardim"  },
  { key: "13", value: "Alfredo Freire I"  },
  { key: "174", value: "Alfredo Freire II" },
  { key: "186", value: "Alfredo Freire III" },
  { key: "217", value: "Alfredo Freire IV" },
  { key: "189", value: "Alvorada I, Jardim" }
]

console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, "  "))
```